# google cloud storage image url works fine but when used in the src of an img html file it goes to the alternative and does not show the image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I have a PERN JS app and from the front (in react) a form has an input type file that sends the file (an image) to the server side. I then uploaded the image in a bucket in google cloud storage with public permission for everything to allUsers. It uploads fine, if I go to the public url provided by google storage i can see the image fine even on incognito window. The problem is when i send the path to a react component to display the image. It has a img html tag that goes to the alternative text property of img html tag and the component never displays the image i want. It uploads with a strange size of 20 B in Google Cloud Sotorage Bucket.

My code:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const gc = new Storage({
  projectId: GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
  keyFilename: GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE,
})
getPublicUrl = (bucketName, fileName) => `https://storage.googleapis.com/best-buds/${bucketName}/${fileName}`


router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        
        const file = req.files && req.files.image
        const bucket = gc.bucket('best-buds');
        const file_bucket = file && bucket.file(file.name)
        const stream = file_bucket.createWriteStream({
          resumable: false,
          gzip: true
        })
        stream.on('finish', () => {
          file.cloudStorageObject = file.name;
          return file_bucket.makePublic()
          .then(() => {
            file.gcsUrl = getPublicUrl('best-buds',file.name);
            next()
          })
        })

        stream.end(file.buffer);


        ...
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    
});

module.exports = router;
```

I used devtools extension and checked my react component receives de props image with the correct url. If i go to that url using the browser i can see the image but still its not displaying in my component.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: `it goes to the alternative and does not show the image` please edit the question to clarify what this means (and to fix the broken code formatting)

Comment: What is the `content-type` set for the image objects?

Comment: I think I know whats happening here, can I see an example image URL?

Comment: @Abhishek thanks for your help! here's an example: https://storage.googleapis.com/best-buds/mascotas-perros-razas-caniche-1280x720x80xX.jpg

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your help! it's either png or jpeg

Comment: @Abhishek so when i upload an image manualy to the GCS platform it stores with a size of 20 KB, but when the upload is done by my script it uploads with a size of 20 B. Could this be? I don't know what is wrong in my code

Comment: The image doesn't seem to be working, can you please type the image link and confirm that its returning the image. I opened it and its showing me "cannot be displayed because it contains errors". Try uploading another image or setting the "firebase storage" rules to allow read.

Comment: I remember this problem, this happens when you try to upload an image to firebase or google cloud platform, you need to store it as blob and assign an extension. I ran into this in 2018 so I don't remember exactly what I did but I remember it was something to do with file getting courrpted during read and upload, so the cloud actually just stores the name and that's it

Comment: also I remember that you have to store the file as a blob and you HAVE TO provide proper metadata, for PNG and JPG there are specific metadata that you need to provide, one field I remember was file-type and depending on the type of file you are uploading, you need to assign,eg: uploading pdf as blob & file-type: pdf

Comment: and if you are looking to assign the blob as a image src then you need to pass it as base64 I think, I don't remember well, I need to look but I remember that there was a conversion of some sort when using that blob back as img src

Comment: @Abhishek that was exactly what was happening!! Thanks so much! I could resolve it by setting what you said!! Thanks again!!

Comment: mention not, for the sake of community and future visitors to this question, I will write a proper answer so that they do not have to go through this pile of comments

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the upload, [uploading files to google cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files), whether that be cloud storage or firebase storage, you will need to pass the file as blob and then you will need to assign proper extension to it with proper metadata, every filetype has its own metadata, for example: a pdf document will have document/pdf or an image will have image/png or image/jpeg. If the upload fails and you get some low byte size file then that means that the upload failed and it is due to metadata really.

```
 var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};
```

[Firebase's doc explains how it works here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata)

---